# EQU was unexpected at this time?

Tags: batch-file

http://pastebin.com/qDZ0Eckq

Hi, when I try to run that batch code of mine, it says EQU was unecpected at this time..?
I have tried     %input% ==      and that says the same message in a way.
When I start the program by the way, it automatically brings it to the last section down at the bottom. I moved it there trying to see if that would solve my problem (it used to be at the top). Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: The pastebin source doesn't contain any code that has '%input% == '.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't posted any clue as to the line of your 140+-line code on which you're getting the error, we are reduced to guessing.

The normal reason for this error is, from your post of **PART** of (presumably) the line in question, `%input% ==`, the reason is quite simple. The variable `input` has no value, so the line becomes

```
IF EQU [well, I don't know the rest since you haven't indicated what it might be]
```

Cure (1)
    IF NOT DEFINED input goto somewhere
    if %input% equ ...

Cure (2)
    if "%input%" equ "whatever" ...

Cure (3)
    if X%input% equ Xwhatever ...

(where X can be virtually any character, or may be appended as a suffix rather than a prefix)

The object being to ensure that BOTH sides of the comparison are non-empty

...BTW,

```
if ERRORLEVEL == 1 goto AdminChat
```

won't work either. `ERRORLEVEL` is a string - it will never be equal to `1`

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto AdminChat
```

Comment: errorlevel being a string and not a value, omg! SO MUCH WASTED DEBUGGING TIME >_< GAH. You're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work:

```
set /p adminpassword=Password:
if errorlevel equ thebulldogtheo goto AdminChatRoom
```

change it to:

```
set /p "adminpassword=Password: "
if "%adminpassword%" equ "thebulldogtheo" goto :AdminChatRoom
```

BTW: you get an errorlevel from the `choice` command, not from `set /p`.